# Mapping protein sequences on an abscissa?

Tags: java, statistics, mapping, bioinformatics

What would you do to represent the distribution of small sequences (<=40 residues) according to their position in their initial protein?

I have several sequences as below. The 1st colum is the number of the current sequence. The second column is the start position and the 3rd column is the stop position of the current sequence in its initial protein.

```
1   18  34  
2   39  55  
3   30  46  
4   20  36  
5   22  46  
6   22  46  
7   25  50  
8   33  50  
9   46  63
```

Those sequences do not come all from the same protein, they come from different proteins which have different length.

What would be the best idea to map those sequences on an abscissa to see if they are more at the beginning of a protein or more at the end or more in the middle, considering that the proteins don't all have the same length?

I wrote an algorithm that map those sequences on the abscissa, according to their start and stop position but the problem is that the graph can't be interpreted since proteins have different length. My graph shows that sequences are more are the beginning of proteins but this is only due to the fact that some proteins are shorter than others, so this is an issue.

Anyone has a better idea for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are the proteins similar enough to do a multiple sequence alignment?  If so then you can align the reads to the multiple sequence alignment so that they are all in the same coordinate space.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. No they're already clusterised at 90% of identity on a global alignment.